# This scheme function seems to be tail recursive, so why am I getting a stack overflow

Tags: recursion, scheme, tail-recursion

I recently have been messing around with scheme for the first time in years.
I'm using repl.it to play around a bit.
I wrote this basic function to take a list and return a doubly-linked list. Each cell of the list is a pair whose car is the list element and whose cdr is a pair with the previous element in car and the next element in cdr.  The first and last elements have null as the previous and next item, respectively.  I wrote the function to be tail recursive.  I know now that scheme actually does have looping syntax, but I was under the impression when I wrote it that the only way to loop in scheme was with tail recursion.  My code is as follows:

```
(define (dbllink li) 
    (letrec ((step (lambda (lis prev head) 
                           (if (null? lis) 
                               head 
                               (let ((cell (cons (car lis) 
                                                 (cons prev '()))))
                                 (if (null? prev) 
                                     (step (cdr lis);<--recursive call
                                           cell 
                                           cell) 
                                     (begin (set-cdr! (cdr prev)
                                                      cell) 
                                            (step (cdr lis);<--recursive call
                                                  cell 
                                                  head ))))))))
        (step li '() '())))
```

I marked what I believe to be the only two recursive calls.  They both seem to me to be in tail context, according to [R6RS](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r6rs/r6rs-std/r6rs-Z-H-2.html#node_toc_node_sec_11.20), yet calling the function causes a stack overflow. Any Ideas as to why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Your code is indeed tail recursive. When I try this out in r6rs in DrRacket I get

```
(dbllink '(1 2 3 4 5)) 
; ==> #0={1 () . #1={2 #0# . #2={3 #1# . #3={4 #2# 5 #3#}}}}
```

This makes a circular structure. I think perhaps BiwaScheme tries to print this and you cannot print list structure with tail recursion and it doesn't check for circular lists so you end up with a stack overflow.

You can verify this by assigning the result instead so that it doesn't print the result.

```
(define test (dbllink '(1 2 3 4 5))   ; ==> #void
(car test) ; ==> 1
test ; ("too much recursion" in Biwa)
```

Comment: Hmm... It's not supposed to be circular.  That is, the next and previous "fields" of the first and last elements respectively are supposed to be null.  or do you just mean that little circles are formed by consecutive elements pointing back and forth at one another?